# How can I use an API (https) in JSON format with Google Actions?

Tags: json, api, webhooks, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I have been trying a lot of stuff to use my API key in Google Actions for developing a google assistant app. Seems like it is only possible to use webhooks in Google Actions console. How can I set something up in a way that it works with my API as well?

ERROR MESSAGE

```
Unsuccessful webhook call due to client issue: Error querying agent endpoint. State: URL_ERROR, reason: ERROR_OTHER.
```

{
"responseJson": {
"message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."
}
}

Comment: I think any connection between APIs will require a webhook. Is there a reason you don't want to use one?

Comment: Thx for your answer. Using a webhook wouldn't be a problem but I think the format of my API doesn't work with a webhook. I don't know how to solve that :( From Google I get the error message that                                                         
                                                                                                                  
   Unsuccessful webhook call due to client issue: Error querying agent endpoint. State: URL_ERROR, reason: ERROR_OTHER.
{
  "responseJson": {
    "message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."
  }
}

Comment: The webhook gives you the ability to manage your API in any way it's supported as the webhook can act as a middleman between your API and Google.